# Functioning domain even when the server is off

Tags: web-services, webserver

Something might be a wrong with my domain name. When i visit the url its still functioning right and shows the default webpage even after the server has been off for weeks now

Comment: are you in control of where the domain is pointing? It must be pointing somewhere... maybe to a page at your registrar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have already tried this, but the two things I would check are:

1. You could be viewing a cached version of the page. This is the most obvious explanation but I'm guessing you cleared your browser cache.
2. You might be viewing a copy on a backup server. That'll depend on whether your NS records have an alternate server specified that isn't off.

Are you sure your server is off? What response do you get when you ping it via the domain name? As this is basic troubleshooting, you may have already tried these things, so if you did, what you encountered may be helpful in diagnosing the cause.

Comment: I found out what's wrong I was using cloudflare and it had a backup of my site, I deleted the copy and everything is back to working order

Comment: @bisera Glad you figured it out. So it turns out there was a copy on a backup server, stoked I was right! This was my first answer on here. :D